# Perforce : How to find the list of files that have modifications from the depot version

Tags: perforce

Is there a command to find the list of edited files that have modifications in my client in perforce. Suppose I have used p4 integrate, all the files are changed to editable mode and finding differences manually is time consuming. "E.g. In CVS if I have the same situation I can do a check-in of all the files, but it CVS would not allow me to check in the files that doesn't have any difference from the depot/repository.

Comment: If you don't want to check in unchanged files, there are various ways to arrange that: (1) change your client spec to say "Submit options: revertunchanged", or (2) issue `p4 revert -a` prior to submitting your changelist. (There are other ways, but this should help you get started.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `p4 diff` command to view diffs of open files.  There are a bunch of flags on `p4 diff` that let you filter the output in various ways; see `p4 help diff`.

A couple of notes on `p4 integrate`:

- there will be no local differences until after you've run `p4 resolve`
- if you have resolved and the result still has no local differences, you probably want to submit the (unchanged) files anyway because this will create a record that those revisions have been integrated.  If you don't, they'll just show up again the next time you integrate.

My preferred workflow for avoiding submits of unchanged files is generally to use `p4 revert -a` before I submit.  This will automatically revert files that I've opened for edit but not changed, but skips unchanged files with pending integration records (since you usually *don't* want to revert those, for the reasons given above).